# Do Windows store apps supports custom gestures?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, touch

i'm beginner to creation Windows store apps. Do Windows store apps supports simple way to make custom touch gestures? I searched in MSDN and I found Tablet PC SDK 1.7 but it's written for Windows XP Tablet PC Edition. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I'm using the [MSGestureEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441180.aspx) in my javascript Windows Store apps but I'm sure there has to be something similar for C# (which I believe is your case)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Gestures and Manipulations sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59. Also see Responding to user interaction (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465397). And if the standard gestures and manipulations aren't enough, you can use [Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) to roll your own.